# Trying to crawl values using scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl the 'Median Gross Monthly Income From Work' from a webpage using the following code:

```
class crawl_income(scrapy.Spider):

     name = "salary"
     allowed_domains = ["stats.mom.gov.sg"]
     url = 'http://stats.mom.gov.sg/Pages/Income-Summary-Table.aspx'

     def parse_data(self, response):
         table_headers = response.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]/td/td')
         salary = []
         for value in table_headers:
             data = value.xpath('.//text()').extract()
             salary.append(data)
         print salary

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(crawl_income)

process.start()
```

But I do not see any values when I was trying to print out the list that I created to store the values.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Firs of all, your code won't work.

`url` should be `start_urls` to let Scrapy know where to start crawling.

`parse_data` should be `parse` because without any information Scrapy does not know which method to call and the default is `parse`. Otherwise you get a `NotImplementedError` too when Scrapy crawls the start URL and the `parse` method is not present.

When I run the code below (which holds all the mentioned changes) and prints the `response.body` to the console I do not find any element with `class="odd"` so I guess there are some AJAX/XHR calls inside the site which then provide the information.

**EDIT**

After looking at your code again I see that the XPath is a bit odd. You use `tr[@class="odd"]/td/td` however one `td` element does not have another `td` as its child. If you want to avoid the headers change your extraction as in the code below. With this change I get results in the `salary` list.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class crawl_income(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "salary"
    allowed_domains = ["stats.mom.gov.sg"]
    start_urls = ['http://stats.mom.gov.sg/Pages/Income-Summary-Table.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.body
        table_headers = response.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]//td')
        salary = []
        for value in table_headers[1:]:
            data = value.xpath('./text()').extract()
            salary.append(data)
        print salary

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(crawl_income)

process.start()
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's start_urls or url, neither is parse or parse_data, it works for my other crawler.

Comment: OK, I looked at the code and the site again and I updated the example. However for me it only works with `start_urls`. Did you indented the code properly to have the parse method inside the body of the class and not as a global method?

Comment: Thanks! It works well! Any idea how could I do multiple crawlers at the same time?

Comment: If it works I'd like if you could accept the answer. For multiple crawlers simply call `process.crawl` multiple times with the spider classes.

Comment: Any example? In one class, I would like to run multiple spiders.

Comment: for example: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process